# Flutter: Navigator.pop(context);

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

I pass a page with this code below.

```
Navigator.push(context,
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FileFolder()));
```

for example, I change some data in `FileFolder();` page. And I want to get this data to my first page what I change data. I use `Navigator.pop(context);` but this code is not run `initstate((){});`. How can I refresh my first page?

Comment: use shared preferences or global variables then call `setState((){})` this will update the data everywhere

Comment: do you need the call back from `FileFolder()` page after the `FileFolder()` page popped out?

Comment: @AdithyaShetty I had understood what you say to me. can you share me how can I define global variable?

Comment: My way is to create a `GlobalVariable.dart` file and initialize or define the `variables` with the `datatypes` then import the file where and whenever the variable is used or updated. If you want I can put up an answer to this question with detailed information in doing this.

Answer (score 2):

```
//first page
    Future data = await Navigator.push(context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FileFolder()));

    setState(() {
      myData = data;
    });

//second page FileFolder
    Map data = {};
    Navigator.pop(context,data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code inside `initstate((){});` method like below:

```
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
     Navigator.push(context,
     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FileFolder()));
    });
```

Comment: If I use this. My first page is not become `pop(context)`. because you push which you say page.